# Electric Potential due to Sphere when cavity is at arbitrary position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

While doing practice question, I came across a question...

> A solid sphere of radius **a** has a cavity of radius **b** which has a uniformly charge distributed with density $-\rho$ and the remaining part of the sphere has charge density $+\rho$. Find the electric potential at the centre of the sphere of cavity. The centre of the cavity is at a distance **c** (**c>b**) from the centre of the sphere.

My approach: I tried to draw this situation. [image]

Note that I have putted +q charge inside the cavity so that the charge density on the surface of cavity could be $-\rho$. However I doubt this step taken by me because $\rho$ is generally used for 'charge per unit **volume**' and I have used it for charge per unit **area**.

Now charge on the surface of sphere $q_1 = \rho (4\pi a^2)$

Charge on the surface of cavity $q_2 = -\rho (4\pi b^2)$

Now $V_{sphere} - V_{cavity}$
$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{kq_1}{a} - \dfrac{kq_2}{b}$$

$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{k\rho (4\pi a^2)}{a} - \dfrac{-k\rho (4\pi b^2)}{b}$$

$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{\rho (a+b)}{\epsilon_0}$$

But it is wrong. Why is that? What mistake(s) did I commit?

Correct answer is

> $\dfrac{\rho}{3\epsilon_0} (\dfrac{3R^2}{2}-\dfrac{2b^3}{c})$

EDIT: After some insight I got a bit near the answer...

$$q_1 = \rho(4/3 \pi (a^3-b^3))$$  $$q_2 = \rho(4/3 \pi b^3)$$
So..$$V_C = \dfrac{\rho}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} (\dfrac{3*4\pi (a^3-b^3)}{2*3a}-\dfrac{4\pi b^3}{3c}) $$ $$= \dfrac{\rho}{3\epsilon_0}(3a^2/2 - \dfrac{3b^3}{2a} -b^3/c)$$

However it still is wrong which means there still a missing concept.:(

Comment: Start with Your very comment that $\rho$ is charge per unit volume and not charge per unit area.

Comment: Note the _unit_ (dimension) of your answer!

Comment: $q_{1} ≠ \rho ( 4πa^2)$

Comment: @AnubhavGoel But at equilibrium position all charges stay at the surface of the conductor

Comment: It is not metal surface that all charges would stay at surface. Charge is uniformly distributed.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel So you mean that even cavity will have charge distributed uniformly in it. and it is given by $q = \rho (4\pi b^3 /3)$

Comment: @AnubhavGoel and i cant understand the reason why potential is also dependent on **c**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35380/discussion-between-anubhav-goel-and-manshu).

Comment: @AnubhavGoel yup...for centre point it is $V= \dfrac{3Q}{2*4\pi \epsilon_0 R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential at center due to +ve
sphere is not correct. What you had
found is when cavity is at center.
However potential due to $-\rho$ is
correct.

First consider no cavity

Potential at center of sphere due to uniformly charged complete sphere $ V = 3kq/2a$

Now, potential due to positive charged sphere $cavity$ at center.

$$ V_{1}= \frac{4\rho π b^3}{3c}$$

Subtract it from potential due to uniformly charged complete sphere

$$V - V_{1}$$

Now potential due to negativeness of cavity

$$ V_{2}=- \frac{4\rho π b^3}{3c}$$

Add it to $$V - V_{1}$$.

Comment: how does it matter if the cavity is not at centre? And how are we  supposed to find it?