# How does one find potential of cavity in a sphere?

Tags: electrostatics

In this article,[Electric Potential due to Sphere when cavity is at arbitrary position](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234116/electric-potential-due-to-sphere-when-cavity-is-at-arbitrary-position)

In the solution he takes potential of sphere, subtracts potential of cavity and then adds potential due to "negativeness of cavity"

What is negativeness of cavity? and why exactly do we have to add and substract these quantites?

My thinking is that we can put origin as center of cavity and the compute potential of cavity. And this potential would be potential of cavity, however this approach is wrong, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not wrong, it's just very cumbersome to calculate the integral (sometimes impossible). Notice that electric potential is a scalar quantity, not a vector quantity. That's why the answerer in the article is able to ad and subtract those quantity without taking the an point as origin or reference.

Comment: I think you're answer is leading me on the right track but it is not detailed enough me to understand with the familarity I have with electrostatics right now